# contact form php handler

Tags: php, backend, contacts

I ve been working on a template I found on the web for a year now, and the contact form they have in is very interesting and I didn't want to change it, but still I want to add a PHP handler page to it to be functional, I managed to write this but it is still not working.
can anyone please tell me where I'm mistaking ?

here is my html:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <form method="post" data-aos="fade" action="contact-form-handler.php">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 mb-lg-0">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <textarea class="form-control" id="" cols="30" rows="10"
                placeholder="Write your message here."></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-6">

              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5 btn-block" value="Send Message">
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My php:

```
<?php 
$name= $_post ['name'];
$visitor_email = $_post ['email'];
$message = $_post ['message'];


$email_form = "contact@asineedit.com";
$email_subject = "new form submition";
$email_body = "user name: $name.\n".
                "user email: $vistor_email.\n".
                        "user message:$message.\n";
$to = "mouad@asineedit.com";
$headers ="from: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .="reply-to:$visitor_email\r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
header("location: News & updates.html");
```

Comment: "not working" in what way, specifically?  When you debug, which specific operation is failing or producing an unexpected result?

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute "name" into tag "input"

```
<input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
<input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
<textarea name="message" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Write your message here."></textarea>


<?php 
$name= $_POST['name'];
```

Comment: I added "name" into tag "input" as suggested:

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">

Comment: use $_POST["name"], uppercase, https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: I added name this way : <input name=" fistname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required>  <input  name="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name"><input name="subject" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject"> <input  name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required><textarea name="message"class="form-control"  cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Write your message here."></textarea>

Comment: and used $_POST["name"] :  <?php 
$firstname= $_post ['firstname'];
$lastname= $_post ['lastname']
$subject = $_post ['subject']
$visitor_email = $_post ['email'];
$message = $_post ['message'];

Comment: $email_from = "contact@asineedit.com";
 $email_subject = "new form submition";
 $email_body = "firstname: $firstname.\n".
     "lastname: $lastname.\n".
     "user email: $vistor_email.\n".
     "subject: $subject.\n".
                                          "user message:$message.\n";
 $to = "mouad@asineedit.com";
 $headers = "from: $email_from \r\n";
 $headers .="reply-to:$visitor_email\r\n";
 mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
 header("location: News & updates.html"); 
echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]) . '!';
?>